# OpenIdDict token for infrastructure service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, openiddict

I have a token authoriztaion (password flow) implemented and it works OK for standard user scenerio (mobile app).

Now I want to call WEB API methods from windows service. I don't want to register Identity user for that.

I would like to generate a static token that windows service could authenticate with. I'm looking for a Google style access token that is generated only once and can be used in many places.

What is the best approach of achieving this with OpenIdDict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best approach of achieving this with OpenIdDict?

Your description roughly corresponds to the OAuth2 client credentials grant. You can find an example showing how to implement this flow with OpenIddict here: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/ClientCredentialsFlow.